# How to dynamically reference mongoDB field names?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

Schema of collection:

```
{
   field_1: "number",
   field_2: "number",
   ...
}
```

I have a query that may reference `field_n` dynamically depending on certain conditions that are not known before hand.

How am I able to write an aggregation pipeline that is able to reference field names dynamically?

Comment: With `"$objectToArray"` and some significant pain.

Comment: ... or do you mean your app determines the field name dynamically?  If so, then in javascript you could use something like `[theDynamicVarWithTheFieldName]: theDynamicVarWithTheValue`, i.e., _bracket notation_.

Comment: no, i meant the mongo server needs to determine the field name dynamically.

Comment: Then `"$objectToArray"` will be helpful.

Comment: Be aware, when you use `$objectToArray` then MongoDB cannot use any index (which is so often part of your questions). In general dynamic field names make index use very hard.

Comment: `$objectToArray` also defeats the purpose because looking up a value in an array is O(N) whereas looking for the value of a property of a object is O(log(N)), which is the point.

Comment: which purpose it defeats, may I ask?

Comment: @AlexBlex If I can dynamically reference the property of an object, then it will be a fast query as this operation will be O(log(N)). If I have to resort to converting the object to an array, then looking up the value is O(N), which is a slow operation. So there is no point in converting it to an array.

Comment: If this pipeline needs to be performant, I suspect there might be a better data model for it.

Comment: The purpose of $objectToArray  is to make it possible to use keys as values. If you need best performance, reconsider your schema and adjust your app. Mongo won't let you eat the cake and have it too, it's just a database.